# Tightening the display of matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I hwas wondering if, besides using `format compact`, there is a way to **make the display of matrices more compact or tighteer** (maybe a third-party package that pre-formats the output of a matrix?)

Here is an example of a matrix displayed in MATLAB with `format compact`

[image]

As you can tell from the image above, there is plenty of white space between columns. The amount of white space between columns is fixed regardless of **how many digits** are printed overall per row or column.

This white space is wasted if the matrix has more columns than it can represent in a single row for a given width of the command window, since when that happens, MATLAB just breaks up the matrix into several submatrices, making it difficult to read them:

[image]

### Addendum:

`format short` helps a bit since it reserves space for only **4** decimals (see the picture below) but is there anything else that makes it even tighter (e.g. something that gives the user control over **how many characters are reserved per entry**)?

For example, compare this

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

with:

[image]

Comment: You can always overload the `disp` method of the numerical class you're working with. This might be a bit messy, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default spacing, while it probably can be changed by someone who [really knows what they're doing](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/), isn't changeable.

If you really need to control how things are displayed, I suggest using the `fprintf(1,'...')` command. That way you can have as much control over how it looks as possible.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure the entries are all integers between 0 and 9 (i.e. one character) then you could use:

```
fprintf([repmat('%d ',1,size(A,2)) '\n'],A');
```

which produces something like

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Otherwise for general integers you can get the *tightest* formatting using:

```
fprintf([repmat(sprintf('%% %dd',max(floor(log10(abs(A(:)))))+2+any(A(:)<0)),1,size(A,2)) '\n'],A');
```

which produces something like:

```
   -111     -3     -2  31061  -2285      2  -2030     -2     -4     34
    579    -31   1166    325 -24273     22    -13     -2     -1    -40
   -150     -2  14166  39317      2     12   5119      9     -7     14
     -4     56   -937  46085   -286     44 -28914    -76  -1477 -26938
  -6661  11121    -63     -4   -275  -2014   4053   -697 -12308   -273
  -2038  -3171  72640   4887    811    252   -114   2214    176     -2
  19837  75428    -21   2038  36152    -11   3782 -33491  11082  -3628
  47025 -42492  73009   6746  -5865 -14310 -51040  -7891     -1   1652
   -223     -3   -566     -4  26892    -13  47538 -26949     -1  58930
  13166     -5    169  78945      7   4135   -681   1863    -83  -2037
```

You could wrap these up as functions or even use them to overload `disp` as suggested in the comments to the OP.